# How to update Sub collection Firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to Update  sub collection all documents.
example: Sensor/userId/Data
I want to update all members. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure thing. You just need to get a reference to the subcollection, which you get from the `DocumentReference`. And on that you simply use the regular method for writing data again: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data. If you're having a hard time making this work, update your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question leaves a lot to interpretation, but in JavaScript you can set (or update) a subcollection this way...

```
firestore.collection(`Sensor`).doc(userid).collection('members').doc(memberId).set(data)
```

See more here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model